# How to "round" a 2D Vector to nearest 15 degrees

Tags: c#, xna, linear-algebra, trigonometry, collision

I'm working on a simple game and I'm trying to simplify part of the 2D collision reaction in the game.  When certain objects hit walls, I'm calculating a collision normal (`collisionPoint - objectCenter`) and reflecting based on that normal.  I'm interested in rounding that normal vector to its nearest 15° but I'm not sure of a good way to go about that.

My current thought is doing something like this

```
float angle = atan2(normal.Y, normal.X) * Rad2Deg;
float newAngle = ((int)(angle + 7.5f) / 15) * 15.0f * Deg2Rad;
vector2 newNormal = vector2(cos(newAngle), sin(newAngle));
```

Is this a reasonable way to do it?  Is there a better way?

Comment: My trigonometry skills aren't what they used to be... but how will rounding to the nearest fifteen degrees simplify anything?

Comment: It's part of the design of the collision response, not anything to simplify the math.

Comment: That code there is probably what I would do.

Comment: Will normal.Y always be positive? If normal.Y is < 0, angle will be < 0. Suppose angle == -38 degrees. You want it to round to -45, but -38 + 7.5 = -30.5 which will round to -30.

Comment: @BobKaufman, that's a good point.  `normal.Y` could be negative...

Comment: 15 degrees is close to .2618 radians. Why don't you just skip the extra conversion step and use that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
float roundAngle = 15 * Deg2Rad;
float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(normal.Y, normal.X);
Vector2 newNormal;

if (angle % roundAngle != 0)
{
    float newAngle = (float)Math.Round(angle / roundAngle) * roundAngle;
    newNormal = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(newAngle), (float)Math.Sin(newAngle));
}
else
{
    newNormal = Vector2.Normalize(normal);
}
```

You don't need to add 7.5, take this example:

```
// 4 degrees should round to 0
    (4 + 7.5) / 15 == 11.5 / 15 == 0.77
// When this gets rounded up to 1 and multiplied by 15 again, it becomes 15 degrees.

// Don't add 7.5, and you get this:
    4 / 15 == 0.27
// When rounded, it becomes 0 and, as such the correct answer

// Now how about a negative number; -12
    -12 / 15 == -0.8
// Again, when rounded we get the correct number
```

Comment: Makes complete sense to use the already existing `Math.Round()` function to handle the negative numbers case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

actually this is more correct if you want the nearest 15 degree angle :
do this:

```
newangle% = INT(((angle%+7.5)/15)*15)
```

INT ALWAYS rounds DOWN by default this should properly give you the nearest angle in any case that is positive or negative have fun!!
and add the part where you use degree to rad and rad to degree if needed INSIDE the parens (like right next to angle% if that angle is not given in degrees then use some sort of rad2deg multiplier inside there
this is more like how you would do this in basic, with some modification It will work in c code or such, well good luck!!

Comment: Actually this is less correct than the OP. The point of casting to `int` is so that when you then multiply by 15 again, the number will be a multiple of 15. Here you have basically done a big circle and ended up with an `int` that contains `angle + 7.5`