# Rotary Dialler Snap to position

Tags: android, rotation

I have made a Rotary switch like one used on a multimeter to select the function of operation.
The code I used to do this is the same as in this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/)

### What I would like to know is:

How can I make the switch "snap" to a position instead of rotation freely as you drag it? (I have 16 function positions arrayed around the switch)

And how can I make it tell me which position it is currently in?

(I have very little knowledge of java and android)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the current X,Y position of the input (touch?) to calculate the angle.

Round the angle to the nearest of the 16 positions. To do this you can use [How to "round" a 2D Vector to nearest 15 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038392/how-to-round-a-2d-vector-to-nearest-15-degrees) but replace 15 with 22.5 (360/16) degrees.

Set the angle of the rotor to the new (rounded) angle.